# Can Visual Studio Code be used to create a SharePoint Online Hosted Add-in?

Tags: sharepoint, add-in

I see the visual Studio Code office add-in guide.

But what about SPO hosted add-in Apps?

Comment: Its one and the same thing, you create it for SPO or on-premise.

Answer (score -4):

To create a SharePoint-Hosted App you can do the following:

1. Click on New Project
2. Under Templates -> Visual C# -> Office/SharePoint -> Apps
3. Select "App for SharePoint". Give a name to your app. Click on OK.
4. A window will open up. There you can select "SharePoint-hosted" to create a SharePoint hosted app. enter the name of the site collection where you want to deploy your app.

Comment: [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543923/jason) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58904614/3744182): *That is Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code. There is no 'New Project' option in VS Code.*